# Null Pointer Exception Error in arrayList add declare

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

when I'm trying to use `sentMessages` method in `testClass`, I got a `NullpointerException` error in the line `receiverUser.privateMessageList.add(privateMessage);`
even I initialized the "privateMessageList" list. How can I deal with this problem?

```
public class User {

    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String userType;
    int topicCount = 0;
    final int maxTopicNumber = 5;

    ArrayList<PrivateMessage> privateMessageList;

    public User(String userName, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String user_type) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.userType = "USER";

    }
    //private message section
    public PrivateMessage sentMessage(String newMessage, User receiverUser) {
        privateMessageList = new ArrayList<>();
        PrivateMessage privateMessage = new PrivateMessage(this.userName, newMessage);
        receiverUser.privateMessageList.add(privateMessage);
        System.out.println("Message sent successfully!");
        return privateMessage;
    }

    public void ListMessages(User receiverUser) {
        System.out.println("Inbox of " + receiverUser);
        for (int i = 0; i < receiverUser.privateMessageList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(receiverUser.privateMessageList.get(i));
            System.out.println("Sent by: " + this.userName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: put "privateMessageList = new ArrayList<>();" inside your constructor

Comment: Thank you! didn't see your comment and I'm sorry for this, appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a `User` and not call `sentMessage` method, your `privateMessageList` will not be created, thus executing any list method will cause NPE.

So initialize `privateMessageList` inside of the constructor or inline.

```
List<PrivateMessage> privateMessageList =new ArrayList<>();
```

Your `sendMessage` method will look like this:

```
public PrivateMessage sentMessage(String newMessage, User receiverUser) {
    PrivateMessage privateMessage = new PrivateMessage(this.userName, newMessage);
    receiverUser.privateMessageList.add(privateMessage); // list is already created
    System.out.println("Message sent successfully!");
    return privateMessage;
}
```

Secondly, if you are creating privateMessageList inside of your sentMessage method, than your list will always have single element. Because another method call will remove previous list. It seems to be a bug.

Comment: It really worked, thanks Sir!

Comment: Glad to help/. but remember, that all messages added to privateMessageList will not be removed by the GC, leading to a memory problem. So you need a point in time when you wil clean this list.

Answer (score 0):

You're NOT initializing `privateMessageList`.

Initialize it in the constructor, so that it's *always* intialized.

Your `sentMessage()` method initializes the `privateMessageList` of `this`. But it doesn't initialize (and shouldn't)  the list of `receiverUser`. 
Each user has its own list. Initializing one user's list won't initialize another user's list.

Initializing it in the constructor makes everything simpler and safer: there is no good reason for a user to ever have a null list.

Comment: _"there is no reason for a user to ever have a null list. "_ -- lazy initialization to save memory could be a reason.

Comment: OK. That would be a reason, but a bad one. It's premature optimization, especially when you're a newbie learning the basics.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm a newbie so I struggle so much while coding, but solved as I initialize the "privateMessageList" in constructor. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

replace this receiverUser.privateMessageList.add(privateMessage); to 
privateMessageList.add(privateMessage);

create ArrayList object inside instance initializer block or inside constructor.

Comment: Initializing the arrayList in constructor worked. Thanks a lot!